# How to caluate cpu cycles as that of QueryPerformanceCounter

Tags: linux

I have the following code in win32 to calculate cpu cycles using QueryPerformanceCounter()

```
LARGE_INTEGER ltime; <br>
UINT32 cycles; <br> 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&ltime);<br>

cycles = (UINT32) ((ltime.QuadPart >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFF);
```

How do I implement the same on ARM cortex A9 (panda board) running Ubuntu (OMAP4) ????

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be to use `clock_gettime` with either `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` or `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`. (see [clock_gettime](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html))

That will give you *"High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU"* and *"Thread-specific CPU-time clock"*, respectively.

Alternatively, one could sum up values returned by `times`, but I guess that would be less precise as it also depends on the scheduler, whereas the above supposedly reads a performance counter from the CPU if possible.